# Testing attribute against list in datomic datalog

Tags: datomic, datalog

I would like to test in a where clause in datalog if an attribute is in a particular set (or list). For example I want to test whether the `:tag-type/code` is  in `["urgent" "todo"]` .  I can do this:

```
   (or
       [?tag-type :tag-type/code "urgent"]
       [?tag-type :tag-type/code "todo"]
        )
```

But I would like to be the list to be a parameter. say `?tag-names` 
So , I would like to do something in the lines of  this :

```
       [?tag-type :tag-type/code *in* [?tag-names])]
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

A friend - without SO account! - has helped me out. 
You can specify a collection in the :in-clause like this :

```
[?collection-name  ...]
```

yielding :

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?tag-type "[*]")
       :in $ [?tag-names ...] 
       :where 
       [?tag-type :tag-type/code ?tag-names]] 
        the-db ["urgent" "todo"])
```